# Cache certain websites for 1 hour regardless of expiration header

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid, cache

In Squid3, how can I cache www.example.org/* for 60 minutes without even checking the internet for updates?

Comment: Are you asking for your own browser or are you setting up a dns server or a caching server? You need to provide a lot more information for this to be a relevant question in this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For squid cache check 'refresh_pattern' option in squid.conf.